# Hide overflow on phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

What I'm trying to do sounds pretty simple, but I can't do it.

I am building a game using [Phaser](http://phaser.io), and on the top bar of my game want to print the picture of the player inside a circle. But I can't find a way to do this.

I find how to do a circle :

```
this.mask = this.game.add.graphics(0,0);
this.mask.drawCircle(50,50,50);
```

But I can't find a way to fill it with a picture, without the picture overflowing the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phaser has support for using an image to mask another.

See the [official Alpha Mask example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/bitmapdata/alpha-mask) for an example with two images. Using an image for the mask might be the recommended method.

I've also created [a JSFiddle that shows how to use a created circle](https://jsfiddle.net/strivinglife/6evr5dnm/):

```
// Create our 'main' state that will contain the game
var mainState = {
    preload: function() { 
        // This function will be executed at the beginning     
        // That's where we load the images and sounds
        this.load.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
        this.load.image('baseImage', 'https://placeholder.baker.com/200');
    },

    create: function() { 
      this.baseImage = this.game.add.sprite(this.world.centerX, this.world.centerY * .5, 'baseImage');
      this.baseImage.anchor.setTo(0.5);

      this.mask = game.add.bitmapData(this.baseImage.width, this.baseImage.height);
      this.mask.circle(this.world.centerX, this.world.centerY * .5, 100, 'rgb(0,200,0)');

      this.bmd = this.game.make.bitmapData(200, 200);
      this.bmd.alphaMask('baseImage', this.mask);
      this.game.add.image(this.game.world.centerX, this.world.centerY * 1.5, this.bmd).anchor.set(0.5);
    },
};

// Initialize Phaser, and create a game
var game = new Phaser.Game(200, 400);

// Add the 'mainState' and call it 'main'
game.state.add('main', mainState); 

// Start the state to actually start the game
game.state.start('main');
```